# How to list total files for every subfolder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script

On google drive I have a directory with over 1000 subfolders. I want to list all subfolders with the total amount of files for each subfolder. This is the script I got so far but it doesn't work cause it's just listing 0 for all subfolders

```
// replace your-folder below with the root folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'CC-Part2';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFolders();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'size'] );

  var subfolder;
  var name;
  var size;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    subfolder = contents.next();
    name = subfolder.getName();
    size = subfolder.getSize();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, size] );     
  }  
};
```

Can anyone help me fix this script?

Answer (score -1):

You can find a script on [labnol.org](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-tree/21198/) which is like the 'tree' command in DOS but for Google Drive.

To get started, click [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwsW5HhjJeDMp0yhnBOFQhLPgbB-VZwBPGls6KrmEhT-NngdsKd/exec) and authorize the script to access the files in your Google Drive. Once the authorization is complete, it may take a minute to generate the entire Google Drive tree. You’ll then get a link to download an HTML file that mirrors your Drive structure. You can directly send the file to the printer as well.

Comment: This is almost a link only answer which are consider low quality posts. Please add the most relevant pars for que referred source as it could be unavailable in the future.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please [edit] the essentials into your text.